# Java - Render images in pdf from html sources

Tags: java

We are currently using Jasper report to generate pdf. But recently we come to problem where we need to render HTML code in pdf. And HTML code contains images. Images sources can be both http URL or base64 string.

How can we solve the problem? Or which library can we use to solve the problem?

Comment: If the data was a base64 you can do like this `<img src="data:image/png;base64,yourbase64Value" alt="something"/>`

Comment: @CyrilleConMorales, we need to render the HTML in pdf. But in jasper report <img> tag is not being rendered.